# Delimiter is being changed with fields

Tags: text-processing, awk

I have a file with values organized in columns, and separated by *commas*, as in the file below:

```
324,01,1,113333600000,1,,
016,01,1,134954200000,1,,
770,01,1,109069200000,1,,
853,01,1,111518800000,1,,
```

When I use the following `awk` command, the *delimiter* is being changed from *commas* to *spaces*

Code:

```
awk -F, '{$4=$4/1024}{print $0}'
```

The output becomes:

```
324 01 1 110677343.75 1  
016 01 1 131791210.93 1  
770 01 1 106512890.62 1  
853 01 1 108905078.12 1
```

How can I change the value of the field without changing the delimiter?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set `OFS` as well:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{$4=$4/1024}1'
```

The `OFS` determines how output fields are delimited. If you don't set it, the default is a space.

Answer (score 7):

muru answer is correct, but I prefer using the BEGIN block for this task:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{$4=$4/1024}1'
```